# Find all possible values of $p$ where $p$ is a prime number.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> **Problem:** Let $p$ be a prime and let $\{a_k\}_{k=0}^{\infty}$ be a sequence of integers such that $a_0=0,$ $a_1=1$ and $$a_{k+2}=2a_{k+1}-pa_k$$ for $k=0,1,2,3,\ldots.$ Suppose that $-1$ appears in the sequence. Find all possible values of $p$.

My Attempt: Note that we obtain $p=5$ if $k=3.$ So we investigate for values of $k$ greater than $3$.Observe that for $k>3$ $a_{k}\equiv 2a_{k-1}\pmod p \Rightarrow a_k \equiv 2^{k-1}\pmod p.$ So if $a_k=-1$  for some $k>3$ we have $$2^{k-1}+1\equiv 0\pmod p.$$
Next, observe that $a_k\equiv 2a_{k-1}-a_{k-2}\pmod {p-1}\Rightarrow a_k\equiv k\pmod {p-1}.$ Thus we have $$k+1\equiv 0\pmod {p-1}.$$ 
This implies $k=M(p)-(1+M),$ which gives us: $$2^{M(p-1)-2}+1\equiv 0\pmod p.$$

Now $p\not= 2$ since $a_k$ will be even and hence never equal to $-1.$ Thus $(2,p)=1$. By Fermat's Little Theorem we also have $$2^{p-1}\equiv 1\pmod p$$ which yields $5/4\equiv 0\pmod p.$ This is the part which has me stumped. I have never seen fractions before and I do not know how to avoid this in this solution. Please help!